# Page does not show correct layout with small screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

The layout starts-off fine when displayed in 751px or greater but does not work fine when it starts-off in 750px or less. I thought this code below in my javascript would work but it doesn't.

```
// does not seem to work when page is loaded
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    window.innerWidth <= 750 ? columnLayout() : rowLayout();
});
```

```js
const colorPickerEl = document.getElementById("color-picker");
const colorSchemeContainerEl = document.getElementById(
  "color-scheme-container"
);
const colorModeEl = document.getElementById("color-mode");
const headerEl = document.getElementById("header");

// display default scheme
displayColorScheme(colorPickerEl.value.slice(1), "monochrome");

/*-------------
Event Listeners
---------------*/

// listen for when a new scheme is requested
document.getElementById("get-scheme-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  displayColorScheme(colorPickerEl.value.slice(1));
});

// listen for when a randomized scheme is requested
document
  .getElementById("randomize-scheme-btn")
  .addEventListener("click", () => {
    displayColorScheme(generateRandomColor());
  });

// does not seem to work when page is loaded
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  window.innerWidth <= 750 ? columnLayout() : rowLayout();
});

window
  .matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 750px)")
  .addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    if (event.matches) {
      columnLayout();
    }
  });

window
  .matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 751px)")
  .addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    if (event.matches) {
      rowLayout();
    }
  });

function columnLayout() {
  document.getElementById(
    "spacer"
  ).style.height = `${headerEl.offsetHeight}px`;
  const colorBars = document.getElementsByClassName("color-bar");
  let barHeight =
    (colorSchemeContainerEl.offsetHeight - headerEl.offsetHeight) / 5;
  for (const bar of colorBars) {
    console.log(bar);
    bar.style.height = `${barHeight}px`;
  }
}

function rowLayout() {
  console.log("row");
  const colorBars = document.getElementsByClassName("color-bar");
  for (const bar of colorBars) {
    bar.style.height = `${colorSchemeContainerEl.offsetHeight}px`;
  }
}

// display color scheme based on user-picked color (or randomized color) and mode
function displayColorScheme(seed) {
  const mode = colorModeEl.value;
  // fetch the scheme using an api
  fetch(`https://www.thecolorapi.com/scheme?hex=${seed}&mode=${mode}`)
    // convert the data from json
    .then((response) => response.json())
    // manipulate the data
    .then((data) => {
      let html = "";
      for (const color of data.colors) {
        const totalRGBValue = color.rgb.r + color.rgb.g + color.rgb.b;
        // 127 + 127 + 127 (the middle threshold)
        const midRGBValue = 381;
        const textColor =
          totalRGBValue <= midRGBValue ? "white" : "black";
        html += `
                    <div class="color-bar" style="background-color:${color.hex.value};"><p class= "text-color-bar" style="color:${textColor};">${color.hex.clean}<p></div>
                `;
      }
      let spacer = `
                <div id="spacer"></div>
            `;
      colorSchemeContainerEl.innerHTML = spacer + html;
    });
}

// generate a random color in hex format
function generateRandomColor() {
  const characters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  const maxLength = 6;
  let color = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    color += characters.charAt(
      Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)
    );
  }
  colorPickerEl.value = "#" + color;
  return color;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

header {
  padding: 30px 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px -4px #222;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="button"],
select {
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
}

#color-picker {
  height: 3.5em;
  width: 10%;
}

p.colorName {
  border: 1.5px solid rgb(70, 70, 70);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

select {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}

.color-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text-color-bar {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}

#color-scheme-container {
  height: 100vh;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  #color-scheme-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #spacer {
    width: 100%;
    /* height: calc(60px + 3.5em - 9px); */
  }
  .color-bar {
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 17.94%; */
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 751px) {
  #color-scheme-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
  }
  .color-bar {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <form id="color-form">
    <input type="color" id="color-picker" value="#008080" />
    <select name="mode" id="color-mode">
      <option value="monochrome">Monochrome</option>
      <option value="monochrome-dark">Monochrome Dark</option>
      <option value="monochrome-light">Monochrome Light</option>
      <option value="analogic">Analogic</option>
      <option value="complement">Complement</option>
      <option value="analogic-complement">
        Analogic Complement
      </option>
      <option value="triad">Triad</option>
      <option value="quad">Quad</option>
    </select>
    <input id="get-scheme-btn" type="button" value="Get Color Scheme" />
    <input id="randomize-scheme-btn" type="button" value="Radomize Scheme" />
  </form>
</header>
<main>
  <div id="color-scheme-container"></div>
</main>
```

Please note that I can't get the height of my header element and assign it to my spacer div, in CSS. I have to go through my JS and set the height there. Any help is greatly appreciated.

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the addeventlistener "load" code working?

Here's a link where you can try out the issue:
https://massuhcolorschemegenerator.netlify.app/

Comment: With what part of your layout do you have problems with CSS? This looks really simple, there is no need to set anything via JS, neither when loading nor when the width changes.

Comment: To see the issue with the layout please use the link and refresh the page at a smaller width value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! All I needed to do was put my code:

```
window.innerWidth <= 750 ? columnLayout() : rowLayout();
```

at the *end* of my **displayColorScheme** function.

It worked perfectly.